# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, unboundlocalerror

I have following simple function to get percent values for different cover types from a raster. It gives me following error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

which isn't clear to me. Any suggestions?

```
def percent(ras):
    temp = arcpy.SearchCursor(ras,"","","Value;Count","")
    for row in temp:
        theval = row.getValue("Value")
        thecount = row.getValue("Count")
        if row.getValue("Value") == 1:
            a = thecount
        if row.getValue("Value") == 2:
            b = thecount
        if row.getValue("Value") == 3:
            c = thecount
        if row.getValue("Value") == 4:
            d = thecount
    return a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Because `if row.getValue("Value") == 1` might be false and so `a` never gets assigned.

Comment: It has value and do gets assigned. I checked it in arcmap interactive python window but can't get it to work in a stand alone script.

Comment: your loop will also only give you the values of the last loop iteration as you are returning out of the loop and not doing anything with each value.

Comment: You could use 3 x elif and an else to see if any values other than 1-4 are encountered.

Comment: I tried that way as well but still hung up with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is pretty much explained [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) and it helped me to get assignments and return values for all variables.